# Plotting tweets according to shape file

Tags: mysql, data-analysis, shapefile

I have tweets stored in MySQL database and I have downloaded a shape file of Melbourne road network. Now, I want to plot only those tweet which lies within shapefile i.e. on the roads.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a GIS solution, no SQL involved:
You can plot your tweets (in QGIS for example) as points using the coordinates and make a geographic selection of the tweets by location; i.e select only tweets that intersect the road (or are contained by the road; there are options you can choose from). You might wanna buffer your road shapefile before that to increase the amount of points selected.